# Grocery CRUD: Adding an explanatory note to a field

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

When clicking add or edit in a Grocery Crud grid, I need to explain what the purpose of a certain field is to assist the user in completing the form by putting some custom text next to the field called "Active" that is a select box, so that it looks like this:

`Active? [Select active] Note: select Yes to ensure that your event is activated.`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was forced to do a bit of a hack, as the client urgently needed this done. I have done it by using jQuery to append a string to the select box on `document.ready()`. If there is a better way, I will gladly adapt, and accept that answer instead, but for now, the above solution works.